# How to debug on server side AX 2012 R2

Tags: debugging, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have highly customized bank statement functionality. The transfer logic starts with calling Controller, the controller extends from SysOperationServiceController.In the controller's main method i have this piece of code :

```
public static void main(Args args)
{
    BankStatementTransferController_SI  controller;

    controller = BankStatementTransferController_SI::newFromArgs(args);
    controller.buildQuery();
    controller.startOperation();
    controller.refreshCallerRecord();
}
```

And i am able to debug this, until startOperation method.
The main logic is executed in other class, that class extends from RunBaseBatch.
Both classes have the "RunOn" property set on "Called from".
I set breakpoints in both classes but after controller.BuildQuery() the process finish and it doesn't stop on any breakpoints.

The question is how to debug this class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try going to Tools>Options>Developer Options, and then uncheck `Execute business operations in CIL` and see if that allows your breakpoints to be hit.

If that doesn't work, then you use Visual Studio with the **AX visual studio tools** installed, which can be installed using the AX Installer, and attach to `Ax32Serv.exe`. Then you place a breakpoint on an AOT object from *inside* Visual Studio using the AX VS tools. See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/debugging-in-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/debugging-managed-code-in-microsoft-dynamics-ax

Then your actual debugging is performed using **Visual Studio** and not the **AX debugger**.

Comment: Thank you Alex, it works with unchecked Execute business operations in CIL